# I18n "format" for errors won't change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Here is my en.yml config (Rails 7)

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
        one: "User"
        other: "Users"
    attributes:
      user:
        first_name: "First Name"
        last_name: "Last Name"
        email: "Email"
        role: "Role"
    errors:
      format: "%{message} for %{attribute}"
      messages:
        blank: "can't be blank"
        too_short: "is too short (minimum is %{count} characters)"
```

I try to change the format for errors. I step in console and do
`I18n.t('errors.format')` -> `"%{attribute} %{message}"`
Other change properly, but format dont.

format change from `"%{attribute} %{message}"` to `"%{message} for %{attribute}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for `I18n.t('errors.format')`, but you have it scoped under `activerecord`. Move it outside of `activerecord` scope:

```yaml
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message} for %{attribute}"
  activerecord:
...
```

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml#L4*